# Circumcenters and Centroids in the Coordinate Plane

Tags: geometry

> Triangle $ABC$ lies in the $xy$-plane such that its circumcenter is the origin,
> its centroid is $(-1,13)$, and the midpoint of side $\overline{BC}$ has coordinates $(9, 18)$. Find the maximum possible value of the product of the coordinates of the point $B$.

How do I find a correlation between the coordinate points and the centers, along with drawing a rough sketch of the triangle?

Answer (score 2):

We will solve for the coordinates of $A$ using the centroid and then find two candidate points for $B$ and $C$, respectively. The one with the greatest product of coordinates will be the one we want.

Since $(9, 18)$ is the midpoint of $\overline{BC}$ we know that $\frac{x_B + x_C}{2}=9\implies x_B+x_C=18$.

Likewise, $y_A+y_B=36$.

The centroid has coordinates $(\bar{x}, \bar{y})$ where $\bar{x}=\frac{x_A+x_B+x_C}{3}=-1\implies\frac{x_A+18}{3}=-1\implies x_A=-21$

A similar calculation shows that $y_A=3$ therefore, $A=(-21,3)$

The circumcenter is the point equidistant from $A$, $B$ and $C$ and since we know it equals $(0,0)$ and we know $A=(-21,3)$ we know the distance squared is $450$.

Therefore, $A$, $B$ and $C$ all lie on the circle given by the solutions to the equation $x^2+y^2=450$.

But $B$ and $C$ also lie on the line whose slope is $-\frac{1}{2}$ and goes through the point $(9, 18)$.

Using the slope and the point we get that $(x_{B}, y_{B})$ and $(x_C, y_C)$ must satisfy $x=45-2y$. Substituting this expression for $x$ into the equation of the circle gives $(45-2y)^2+y^2=450\implies y^2-36y+315=0\implies (y-15)(y-21)=0$ which gives us candidate $y$ coordinates of $15$ and $21$. Plugging these into the equation of the line gives candidate points of $(15, 15)$ and $(3,21)$.

Since $15^2\gt3\cdot 21$, $B=(15,15)$ and the maximum product is $225$.